# pure javascript select child dom

Tags: javascript

I'm learning not use jquery only pure javascript, just start and have trouble .....
how to select child dom

```
<div class="row-button">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

I'm trying below code but all shows error message.

```
var submit_button = document.getElementsByClassName("row-button");
console.log(submit_button.nodeType); //undefined
console.log(submit_button.firstChild); // undefined
console.log(submit_button.childNodes[0]);  // TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'submit_button.childNodes[0]')
```

or I thought maybe need to add window onload to  sure dom ready so

```
window.onload = function () {
    var submit_button = document.getElementsByClassName("row-button");
    console.log(submit_button.nodeType); //undefined
    console.log(submit_button.firstChild); // undefined
    console.log(submit_button.childNodes[0]);  // TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'submit_button.childNodes[0]')
}
```

Comment: Try `submit_button[0].firstChild`

Comment: getElementsByClassName – that is plural in the method name for a reason.

Comment: Why would you ever learn *not* to use jQuery, seems counterproductive ?

Comment: @adeneo for fun and curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention: it's `getElement`***`s`***`ByClassName`.

This means it returns a NodeList (an array-like object) of matching elements.

Try:

```
submit_button = document.querySelector(".row-button");
```

This will not only add support for IE8, but also return a single element, that being the first element with the desired class.

Answer (score 0):

```
getElementsByClassName("row-button")
```

returns an array of elements of class `"row-button"`. So to get its first (and only in your code) child, use

```
 var submit_button = document.getElementsByClassName("row-button")[0];
```